# Xamarin и скорость загрузки

Tags: xamarin

Как можно ускорить загрузку приложения кроме https://xamdev.ru/5-ways-to-boost-xamarin-forms/ Просто у меня скорость запуска приложения 5 секунд, а если добавлю 7

Comment: Этот список оптимизаций должен состоять из одного пункта - если не устраивает скорость - либо переходите на нативные технологии, либо допиливайте xamarin самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, для Xamarin Forms это нормально

Answer (score 1):

5 секунд без xamarin тоже многовато. вот официальная дока по разгону [Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance), [ios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/performance) и [ведра](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/performance).

минимизируйте количество строк от onCreate до отрисовки формы.
очень важно, имхо:

> Choose the Correct Layout

пример там, конечно, дебильный, но стоит ещё раз прочекать UI на предмет оптимизации.

+не забывайте про профилировку!